# Pipenv Install Rasa incorrect version

Tags: python-3.x, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

When installing `rasa` using `pipenv` with:

```
pipenv install --pre rasa
```

Everything is installed, with some erroneous dependencies being created, but fixed with `pipenv lock --pre --clear`

However, when trying to use `rasa` command in the terminal post-installation, it does not work -> `rasa -h` => `rasa' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`...

How to use `rasa` with `pipenv` ?

Also, when checking the `pipfile.locl` , the wrong version is installed

[image]

Why is `rasa="*"` installing this wrong version ?!

Answer (score 0):

Use python 3.6 or 3.7 and then install pipenv, it solves the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).